# comments not in chronological order - bug?

Tags: support

In the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929088/adding-string-variables-c/32929330#32929330), the [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929088/adding-string-variables-c/32929330#comment53684875_32929330) shown there was posted shortly before the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929088/adding-string-variables-c/32929330#comment53684865_32929330). (In fact, the first is a reply to the second, with a quote from it.)

Comments are supposed to be shown in chronological order, so this is a bug - right? Is it a known issue?

I don't know if the first-posted comment was edited, if that might trigger the behavior.

Comment: You can change the ordering of the comments via the tabs just above the first answer

Comment: @user3791372, that appears to change the order of the answers, not comments.

Comment: ah forgive me. Tired eyes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other user deleted their original comment which was actually posted before yours and re-posted it after you had replied to them. They are in chronological order.

Comment: I see from your profile that you work for SO. Can regular users can see deleted comments?

Comment: Only moderators can see deleted comments.